# Importing Prophet Projection file into SAS

Tags: sas, prophet

Our customer has provided us with a Prophet ".projection" file, which appears to be a binary file (lots of special characters when opening in notepad - `?Š…kÿd?Š…kÿd?` ).

My question is - how can this file be imported into SAS?  The file was generated from Prophet version 8.1 (PE).  In Prophet 7.3 it was possible to use Readbin73 to do the binary->text conversion of the PRJs etc.  Is there anything similar for 8.1?

Comment: Never heard of Prophet; might need to ask them.  There's probably no way to read this directly in SAS; you'd need to convert it to a text file first.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Prophet Workspace (.PRW) file to which your .projection file relates.
2. Click on Results & Runlogs in the sidebar and expand the option that says "ResultType: Projection".
3. In the upper left corner of the ribbon you will see two options:
4. "Copy Grid" allows you to copy the data to the clipboard, after
   which you can paste the tab separated data in the programme of your
   choice.
5. "Copy Grid to Excel" allows you to export the data
   directly to Excel.

You can then prepare the data for SAS.

These steps work in Prophet 8.2.